# What legal code could trigger C4523 "multiple destructors specified" Visual C++ warning?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, destructor, compiler-warnings

According to MSDN, Visual C++ can emit [C4523 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86scb1af.aspx) *'class' : multiple destructors specified*. How is such situation even possible?

I tried the following:

```
class Class {
    ~Class();
    ~Class(int);
};
```

which yields *a destructor must have a 'void' parameter list* error and C4523 warning and the following

```
class Class {
    ~Class();
    ~Class();
};
```

which yields *member function already defined or declared* error and the following

```
class Class {
    int ~Class();
    ~Class();
};
```

which yields *a destructor cannot have a return type* error.

So how do I have C4523 warning and no error?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "none".

Answer (score 3):

The following causes warning C4523 but it is also preceded by an error

```
struct Foo 
{
  ~Foo() {}
  ~Foo() const {}
};


error C2583: 'Foo::~Foo' : 'const' 'this' pointer is illegal for constructors/destructors
warning C4523: 'Foo' : multiple destructors specified
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another example of multiple destructors being an error, not a warning:

```
class C
{
    ~C();
    ~C() volatile;
};
```

Comment: I've never seen a volatile function before.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It's much like the `const` tag that Praetorian added an example of.  I considered using `const` because more people are familiar with it, but felt there was more of a legitimate reason to have a different destructor for a `volatile` object.  But the C++ standard thinks differently, the `volatile` modifier is allowed on ordinary member functions but not the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess: could it be through multiple class inheritance?  Say if class C inherits from both class A and B, and A and B specify a destructor but C doesn't.

Comment: Then a default destructor will be generated - no reason for warning.